# Showing $f_n(x):=\frac{x}{1+n^2x^2}$ uniformly convergent in $\mathbb R$ using $\epsilon-n_0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-convergence, epsilon-delta

I want to show $$f_n(x):=\frac{x}{1+n^2x^2}$$ is uniformly convergent in $\mathbb R$ using $\epsilon-n_0$ argument.

So $|f_n-f|\leq\frac{|x|}{1+n^2|x|^2}$

I know $|f_n-f|\leq\frac1n$  since $\frac1n$ is the maximum of $f_n$. I can show this using the derivatives of $f_n$.

My question is: Can you show this or any other equation (independent of $x$) without using derivatives in any calculation?

I've tried $|f_n-f|\leq \frac1n \iff -\frac1n\leq\frac{x}{1+n^2x^2}\leq\frac1n \iff\ldots$ but I get no inequality which is obviously right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$$\frac x{1+n^2x^2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in\Bbb R$$

You want to prove that

$$\forall\,\epsilon>0\;\;\wedge\;\;\forall\,x\in\Bbb R\;\;\exists\,N_\epsilon\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;\;n>N_\epsilon\implies\;\left|\frac x{1+n^2x^2}\right|<\epsilon$$

But

$$\left|\frac x{1+n^2x^2}\right|=\frac{|x|}{1+n^2x^2}<\epsilon\iff n^2>\frac1{|x|\epsilon}-\frac1{x^2}$$

Thus we can choose

$$\;N_\epsilon:=\frac1{2\epsilon}\;,\;\;\text{so}\;\;n>N_\epsilon\implies n^2>\frac1{4\epsilon^2}\ge\frac1{|x|\epsilon}-\frac1{x^2}\;$$

$$\text{Why? Check the maximum of the function}\;\;f(x)=\frac1{x\epsilon}-\frac1{x^2}$$

once for $\;x>0\;$ and once for $\;x<0\;$ .

Comment: thanks. very nice solution. $\frac1{4\epsilon^2}\geq f(x)$ is equivalent to $(x\pm2\epsilon)^2\geq0$. just a typo: $N_\epsilon=\frac1{2\epsilon}$ ;)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: I think there's a typo. Solving for $n^2$ which makes the function less than $\epsilon$ should give $n^2>\frac{|x|}{\epsilon}-\frac{1}{x^2}$. Correct? How would this change the solution?

Comment: @Mathemanic, if you meant the right side of the inequality after "But" (6th line in the answer), that seems to be correct. Did you try to do the maths there?

Comment: Yes, please see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775497/prove-fracx1n2x2-is-uniformly-convergent/775512?noredirect=1#775512

Comment: @Mathemanic, I insist: it is correct, as we have $$\frac{|x|}{1+n^2x^2}<\epsilon\iff |x|<\epsilon+\epsilon n^2x^2\iff \epsilon n^2x^2>|x|-\epsilon\iff n^2 >\frac1{\epsilon |x|}-\frac1 {x^2}$$ Please do check this and if you still insist there's a mistake please do pinpoint it. Either you or I are mistaken, and after checking this severla times it'd surprise it is me, in spite of all my mistakes in the past.

Comment: Ah, you're right! My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that $\frac x{1+n^2x^2}\leq \frac 1n$ by just multiplying with both denominators. Then, you have to show that $a\leq 1+a^2$ (with $a=xn$). Whit is true, because when $a\geq 1$, $a^2\geq a$, and when $a\leq 1$, $a\leq 1+a^2$. For the other inequality, you have to show that $a\geq -1-a^2$. Substitute $b=-a$ and multiply both sides with $-1$: $b\leq 1+b^2$. From above, we know this is true.

Answer (score 0):

Yet a third approach could be to find the maximum value of $f_{n}$ for each $n$. obviously the limit as $\vert x \vert \to \infty$ of $f_{n}(x)$ is zero. Furthermore, taking the derivative gives
$$ f^{\prime}_{n}(x)= \frac{1-n^2x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}$$
The denominator is never zero and the numerator is zero precisely when $x=\pm \frac{1}{n}$. One easily finds $\frac{1}{n}$ to be the critical point at which $f_{n}$ achieves a max. The value of $f_{n}$ at this value is $\frac{1}{2n}$. Since this is a global max, it bounds  $f_{n}$ uniformly from above. The minimum occurs at the other critical point which gives you a bound below.